# How to compute the iteration matrix for nth NLBGS iteration

Tags: python-3.x, openmdao

I was wondering if there was a direct way of computing the iteration matrix for nth Linear Block Gauss Seidel iteration within OpenMDAO?

thank you

Comment: Do you mean to ask about the LinearBlockGaussSeidel method? The nonlinear version of the algorithm doesn't have an iteration matrix.

Comment: yes I meant the Linear method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are referring to the matrix-form of the Gauss Seidel algorithm where you take Ax=b, and break A up into the Diagonal (D), Lower (L) and Upper (U) parts, then use those parts to compute the next iterate. 
Specifically you compute [D-L]^-1. This, I believe is what you are referring to as the "iteration matrix" (I am not familiar with this terminology, but based on the [algorithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gauss-SeidelMethod.html) I'm comfortable making an educated guess).

This formulation of the algorithm is useful to think about and a simple way to implement it, but OpenMDAO takes a different approach. The LBGS algorithm implemented in OpenMDAO is set up to work in a matrix-free manner. That means it only interacts with the linear operator methods `solve_linear` and `apply_linear` and never explicitly assembles the A matrix at all. Hence there isn't an opportunity to split A up into D, L, U.

Depending on the way you constructed the model, the A matrix you would need might or might not be there at all because OpenMDAO is capable of working in a completely matrix free context. However, if **all** of your components use the `compute_partials` or `linearize` methods to provide partial derivatives then the data you would need for the A matrix does exist in memory.

You'll have to dig for it a bit, and ironically the best place to see how to do that is in the **[direct solver](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/5829f1cc521aec0305b9c53e43e036e9122f86c7/openmdao/solvers/linear/direct.py#L258-L266)** which does actually require the matrix be formed to compute a factorization.

Also, in that code you'll see [a function](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/5829f1cc521aec0305b9c53e43e036e9122f86c7/openmdao/solvers/linear/direct.py#L217-L256) can iteratively call the linear operator to construct a dense matrix even if the underlying components don't provide their partials directly. Please note that this approach for assembling the matrix is **extremely slow** and is not recommended for normal operations.